# Override view ARDunningLetterList with join

Tags: acumatica

I need to add a BAccount custom field in the grid of the screen AR521000 (ARDunningLetterList).

My custom field :

[image]

I overrided the view DunningLetterList :

[image]

I was able to add the custom field in the grid, then I published, but now I have this error : Invalid object name 'ARDunningLetterList' :

[image]

What am i missing ?

Thank you so much and sorry for my english, and for not being able to publish a correct post....where "Hi everyone" should appear at first... !!